# Mongoose transaction gives Attempted illegal state transition from [TRANSACTION_COMMITTED] to [TRANSACTION_ABORTED] when Express response sent inside

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use Mongoose transactions (specifically the form `mongoose.connection.transaction`, not `startTransaction` see `Connection#transaction()` at this location: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html).

I have found that if I try to send an Express response inside the transaction it gives the error:
`Attempted illegal state transition from [TRANSACTION_COMMITTED] to [TRANSACTION_ABORTED]`

...so for example, this gives the error:

```
await mongoose.connection.transaction(async (session) => {

//...a bunch of mongoose stuff here - it doesn't really matter what it is.

res.status(200).json({someObject});

}
```

...but this works fine:

```
await mongoose.connection.transaction(async (session) => {

//...a bunch of mongoose stuff here - it doesn't really matter what it is.

}
res.status(200).json({someObject});
```

Why does the second one work but the first one fail?  There's no return statement for the `res.send` - I can put code after it that executes fine.

Also the DB has the desired resulting state in either case.

...but if I have the response inside the transaction it fails, and outside it works.

Now you may say, "Just take your response out of the transaction."  Yes, indeed.  ...but I want to understand why!

(Mongoose 7.0.1, Express 4.17.3, Node 16.20.0)