# Error "Variable 'someVar' is used before being assigned" but it is definitely being assigned

Tags: javascript, typescript

This code demonstrates the problem:

```
    let someVar: number;

    const someFunc = async () => {
      someVar = 1;
    }

    await someFunc();

    if (someVar == 1) {
      console.log('It is 1');
    }
```

This will give the error:
`Variable 'someVar' is used before being assigned`

...but I don't see how it is possible that it would not be assigned.

Yes I understand I can return the value from `someFunc` and assign it to `someVar` there.  I'm not asking how to fix this code, I'm asking why do I get the error.

(The real problem is that the function is actually a callback passed to `mongoose.connection.transaction` so I don't have access to its return value - I have to assign it from within the function).

(TS 4.5.4, node 16.20.0)

NOTE: This is NOT a duplicate of [Variable 'test' is used before being assigned - Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44832316/variable-test-is-used-before-being-assigned-typescript)

The answer there is that properties of an object are being assigned to before the object itself has been initialized.  This has nothing to do with what is being discussed there other than the error.

Context:

```
let someVar;

await mongoose.connection.transaction( async (session) => {

//atomic mongoose stuff happens here.

someVar = await SomeModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {newThing});

}

if(someVar)... //error!
```

I get in my simplified example I could return the value and assign it, but because it is actually a callback I don't have direct access to the return value of the function.

Why don't I just declare and use `someVar` in the mongoose transaction and avoid side effects?  Because I need to send it as a response and I'm running into this:
[Mongoose transaction gives Attempted illegal state transition from [TRANSACTION_COMMITTED] to [TRANSACTION_ABORTED] when Express response sent inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76343030/mongoose-transaction-gives-attempted-illegal-state-transition-from-transaction)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Typescript, but shouldn't it be `let someVar = number;`? Using *=* rather than *:*?

Comment: @mykaf no......

Comment: What is the actual code since that would not run. It would produce an error about await in the top level.

Comment: @mykaf No, the :number is saying that it is of type number and I have no provided a value.

Comment: @epascarello Imagine it is in an async function.

Comment: Is it *Typescript* complaining, or is this a runtime error? I cannot reproduce this error given this code…

Comment: Typescript complaint.  Violates `no-use-before-define`

Comment: ["no-use-before-define" is an ES Lint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-use-before-define), ES Lint and Typescript are two independent separate products/technologies. Besides all that, you could initialize someVar to a value like 0 or -1 to get rid of the issue.

Comment: You are correct - it isn't ES Lint being triggered as the IDE isn't quoting an ES Lint violation.  Its just a pure TS violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript's ability to follow your control flow and infer types is limited. It can't really execute your whole program for you and figure out types.

So when TypeScript asses wether your variable was assigned before use, here is what it sees:

- An uninitialized variable `let someVar: number;`
- Then a function is called of the type `() => Promise<void>`
- Then you try to use `someVar` which never saw in an assignment *in this scope*.

---

There's not a way to declare that a function has *side effects* that would influence the types in a scope. Here a "side effect" means that it mutates some value outside of it's own scope.

Without understanding your real goal, it's hard to give an explantation of how to fix it, but in this case it would probably be better to return the value instead so that the assignment can be done in the right scope.

For example:

```
async function foo() {
  let someVar: number;

  const someFunc = async () => 1;

  someVar = await someFunc();

  if (someVar == 1) { // works fine
    console.log('It is 1');
  }
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egFAShgG8AoGGAGwFNkYR0BbKgNWACcAuGCBBgIypsA3CTIwomELXpMAYklgBeGKEiwCMRQD4YARhFiZLdppUB3YKmmMq86AQPlUcGLiOs2m5bsKly5CQh6agA6CnQAc1wAcgBJWlQQPWj8EXIAXxJMkiA)

This approach is generally better, since minimizing the side effects of functions is a good thing, when possible.

---

If you can't access the return value, then you need to initialize the variable since typescript cannot see inside your functions like you want.

Initialize to `undefined` and then narrows that type after the function runs to make sure it got set.

```
async function foo() {
  let someVar: number | undefined; // add undefined to type here

  const someFunc = async () => {
    someVar = 1
  };
  
  await someFunc();
  if (someVar === undefined) throw new Error("someVar was not set")

  // type of `someVar` here is now `number`
  
  if (someVar == 1) {
    console.log('It is 1');
  }
}
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egFAShgG8AoGGAGwFNkYR0BbKgNWACcAuGCBBgIypsYAHxhIAJlTioIVcQG4SZGFEwha9JgDEksALwxQkWARh6AfMWXlNLdmZgBGZQF9F5ZcADuwVBsZUOtAE7jCocDC4tqxCenFiEJLSsuKEyAAWbOhe3FQ5AKJsWWy4AETR9j4g3OgaNKX4SuQA9M0wyGAADlQw6BEABhVs-TDpgj2o1RDZMP08-IL9ysrhkUNmBo6EpOTkqhD01AB0FOgA5rgA5ACStJNOl-ihLiQvJEA)

---

You could use use the `!` type operator to say that you want to allow the variable to `undefined`, but every time you access it you want to assume it exists.

```
async function foo() {
  let someVar!: number; // note the ! here

  const someFunc = async () => {
    someVar = 1
  };
  
  await someFunc();

  if (someVar == 1) {
    console.log('It is 1');
  }
}
```

This is less ideal, as this makes your code less type safe. This means that it will never check if the assignment happened, and if it doesn't for some reason, you may get a runtime crash instead of a compile time error.

So this should be considered a last resort.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egFAShgG8AoGGAGwFNkYR0BbKgNWACcBCALhggQYBGVNgG4SZGFEwha9JgDEksALwxQkWARjKAfMQnk5LdtpgBGCQF8x5CcADuwVLMZVF0AmImo4MXEdY2bVUzQlJycikIemoAOgp0AHNcAHIASVpUEHMU-BsYSxJCkiA)

Comment: mongoose.connection.transaction( async (session) => {stuff});
I set the value of a variable in the callback function passed into the mongoose transaction function.  ...then I try to use it after. 

The issue is that, I don't actually have access to the return value of the (session) => {} function.

Comment: I couldn't use ! because null is a value I want to test for and it would even give me the error when checking for null.

Your second option is close to what I did although after ensuring it was not undefined, it would assume the type is `never`.  At that point I did
`someVar = someVar as unknown as number`
and that fixed it.

Thanks for your persistence.